Continuity of a function $f: (X,\mathcal T)\to \mathbb{R}$, where $(X,\mathcal T)$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}$

$(X,\mathcal T)$ is subspace of euclidean space $\mathbb{R}$, where $X=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ and topology $\mathcal T$ is induced by $\mathbb R$. Show that $f: (X,\mathcal T)\to \mathbb{R}$, where $$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & x\in[0,1] \\
      2, & x\in[2,3] \
   \end{cases}
$$ is continous.

The problem is similiar to this one here. Obviously this solution is the first thing I thought of. But I was quickly reminded of the following:

Theorem Function $f:X\to Y$ is continous if and only if inverse image of every closed set in $Y$ is closed set in $X$.

Now using this fact, since $\{1\}\in\mathbb{R}$ is closed and $f^{-1}(\{1\})=[0,1]$ and since $[0,1]$ is open in $X$ wouldn't this lead to a contradiction?

Sets can be open and closed.

@user408858 yeah, I totally forgot about that :/

Does this answer your question? How to prove that $f:[0,1]\cup[2,4]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous using topology?

@Jakobian No! As I've literally stated in the question that it doesn't. Anyways I got my answer.

Changing number from $4$ to $3$ doesn't make a difference

@Jakobian I provided a link to that question and said that answer to it doesn't answer my question. Mine was more about if using the stated theorem could bring us to the contradiction and if not, why not. Next time please read the whole question.

Notice that the complement of $[0,1]$ is $X-[0,1] = [2,3]$ which is open in $X$ because $X$ has the induced topology. This means that $[0,1]$ is also closed in $X$ so there is no contradiction.
Edit: It is important to stress that a set can be both open and closed at the same time!

$[0,1]$ is both open and closed in $X$. Note that in general, if a set $A\subseteq X$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ then it is automatically closed in $X$ with the subspace topology. (because then $A=A\cap X$, the intersection of $X$ with a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$)
